# Appcelerator fails to publish Android app after update (Android SDK version 5.1.1 not found.)

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

Fails to work after update, keep saying "Android SDK version 5.1.1 not found."

[image]

but it's already installed

[image]

Tried a clean install and still getting same error

Using:
Appcelerator Studio 4.8.1.201612050850

Comment: Do you... by any chance, have a newer than SDK 23 installed (24 or higher). You can manage SDK's by going to the directory where they're installed

Comment: @RenePot I have the following directories under ~/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms: android-14, android-16, android-19, android-21, android-22, and android-23. It does not have 24 or higher.... but how do I install it via Appcelerator Studio?

Comment: Can you run, app ti info -t android and see Android 5.1.1 is detected in the terminal as well. How did you install the android updates?

Comment: @KondalKolipaka The results are in this gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2bb1baf7632d9c4e22b64268c8fb47cb , seems like there're a bunch of errors....  The android updates are installed through Appcelerator Studio as in the above image by going to 'Preferences/Platforms/Android'

Answer (score 0):

Have you by any chance updated your Java version at the same time? I had a similar issue with Java 8 and had to downgrade it again to 7.

Comment: Tried installing through here https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US (as per instructions on this page https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+Oracle+JDK#InstallingOracleJDK-OSX) and restarted Appcelerator Studio but still getting the same error. Do I have to set anything after installation?